# Implementing Android Notifications with Oracle server

Tags: android, oracle, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement push notifications for a mobile app which has its server based on Oracle. I have already implemented normal Push notification in Android using a PHP and SQL server in the back end and this is the first time I am implementing using a Oracle server and it seems that there can be no PHP code on the Oracle side but not sure about that fact.

I have surfed across Google and found out some good links but nothing great. 
[A tutorial to implement the Oracle based push notifications](http://deepakcs.blogspot.ae/2013/06/adf-mobile-push-notifications-with.html), [Oracle Documentation on implementing Push Notification](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/push_notification_support_and_provide) and [Oracle Documentation to get started with the implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/getting_started.htm#ADFMF170). As you can see from all the links, there is no hint of usage of a solid Java Code but rather there is a completely different set of rules and protocols that has to be followed to achieve it.

I am a mid-level android developer trying to figure out what's going on but all in vain. Can anybody please speak android to me ?

Comment: (not related to your question) can you please give a link to a repo or article where you learnt from, for the push notifications you did for php sql server, i want to do that and can't find anything on it. It would be a great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@San, You can try checking Oracle Push Cloud Service. There is a step by step procedure on how to implement Android Notification in [Oracle Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCFA/android/step-by-step/). They also have instructions on how to set up your android app for GCM to sending messages to individual users using OPCS.